# F-statistics and coefficient p-value of model with only one variable

Tags: p-value, linear-model, regression-coefficients, f-statistic

F-test tests the null hypothesis that all coefficient of variables in the model equal to zero.

P-value in a hypothesis test shows the probability of having observed results if null hypothesis is true.

My question is that if the model only has one variable, just like `m2` and `m3` shown as following, is the result of f-statistics just the same as the p-value?

**Dataset**
Regarding the dataset. The original dataset has 50 states. `Alaska` and `Texas` are the outliers. From some analysis, I already decide to remove `Alaska` as it has a large effect on the linear model according to the regression results. Now the problem is whether `Texas` should be removed.

`area.no.alaska` has 49 states, `Alaska` is removed
`area.no.tx.al` has 48 states, `Alaska` and `Texas` is removed

I am trying to compare `m2` with `m4` to figure out which is better.

So far, I think `m2` is better because it has higher r-square, higher p-value of variable `land.area` even though both models have p-value very close to zero for variable `land.area`. I am not sure whether it is necessary to compare f-statistics as only one variable in the model and I already compared the p-value of that variable.

```
m2 = lm(area.no.alaska$farm.area ~ area.no.alaska$land.area)
m4 = lm(farm.area ~ land.area, data = area.no.al.tx)
```

> summary(m4)

````
Call:
lm(formula = farm.area ~ land.area, data = area.no.al.tx)

Residuals:
   Min     1Q Median     3Q    Max 
-41309  -8736  -1784   4361  36054 

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error t value      Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) -569.41436 4310.67726  -0.132         0.895    
land.area      0.46526    0.06404   7.266 0.00000000365 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 16300 on 46 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.5344,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.5242 
F-statistic: 52.79 on 1 and 46 DF,  p-value: 0.000000003646
```
````

> summary(m2)

````
Call:
lm(formula = area.no.alaska$farm.area ~ area.no.alaska$land.area)

Residuals:
   Min     1Q Median     3Q    Max 
-50695  -8712   -228   7825  49354 

Coefficients:
                            Estimate  Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)              -8365.76964  4367.14590  -1.916   0.0615 .  
area.no.alaska$land.area     0.62171     0.05716  10.877 1.98e-14 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 18620 on 47 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.7157,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.7096 
F-statistic: 118.3 on 1 and 47 DF,  p-value: 1.981e-14
```
````

Comment: m4 uses the data "area.no.al.tx" and m2 uses the data "area.no.alaska". How are these data sets different? It is no possible to answer this question without knowing that. Otherwise, the models appear to be the same, so I am not sure why you are getting different t-values for land.area.

Comment: thanks. I just updated question with description of the datasets

Answer (score 1):

The only difference between these two models is that m4 excludes one observation (Texas) that is not included in m2. That the R-squared is higher is focusing on the wrong thing. Why did you remove this observation? Generally, it is not a good idea to remove data from a model for the explicit purpose of improving fit (that is considered "cooking the data"). However, it is appropriate to remove an outlier and assess the effect it has on the analysis. It little effect, then leave it in. If it makes a big difference, then you should report both.

In the above, both models are statistically significant with a strong relationship between land area and farm area. Is there a theoretical reason for excluding Texas? Would your interpretation really be different based on m4 instead of m2?

Comment: I remove Texas because it is an outlier. I build ```m2``` and ```m4```  to decide how to deal with this outlier. ```Alaska``` is another outlier. I built a model with ```Alaska``` removed, and the regression result shows it is better to remove```Alaska```.